# Exactly same values for accuracy in RFECV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation, rfe

I'm trying to fit a logistic regression with RFECV. That's my code:

```py
log_reg = LogisticRegression(solver = "lbfgs", 
                             max_iter = 1000)
random.seed(4711)
rfecv = RFECV(estimator = log_reg,
              scoring = "accuracy", 
              cv = 10)

Model = rfecv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with my data or my code, but the accuracy is exactly the same for almost every different value of feature size:

```
Model.grid_scores_
array([0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776,
       0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776,
       0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776,
       0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76200776, 0.76556425,
       0.80968999, 0.80962074])
```

How can this happen? My data is quite big (more than 20000 observations). I cannot imagine that in every fold of the cross validation the same cases are estimated correctly. But if so how could this happen? 1 variable can explain as much as 19 can but not as much as 20 could? Then why don't take the first and the 20th? I'm really confused.

Comment: Hi Tobi! What is the array you posted? Is it the feature importances?

Comment: Hi Arturo! It's `rfecv.grid_scores_`. It's the accuracy for each feature size from 1 to 22 (full model)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all your accuracies are the same because `LogisticRegression` uses L2 regularization by default. That is, `penalty='l2'` unless you pass it something else.

This means that even when `Model` is using all 22 features, the underlying algorithm `log_reg` is penalizing the beta coefficients using L2 regularization. So if you prune the least important features, it won't affect the accuracy because the underlying logit model with 22 features has pushed the coefficients of the least important features close to zero.

I suggest you try:

```py
# Model with no penalty
log_reg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', 
                             max_iter=1000,
                             penalty='none')

# Set seed
random.seed(4711)

# Initialize same search as before
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=log_reg,
              scoring='accuracy', 
              cv=10)

# Fit search
rfecv.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Tell us how it went
rfecv.grid_scores_
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I got the following error message: `Logistic Regression supports only penalties in ['l1', 'l2'], got none` :(

Comment: Is `log_reg` an `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` object?

Comment: Yes, it is: `from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression`

Comment: Could you check your version? `sklearn.__version__`

Comment: The version is `'0.20.3'`

Comment: Try updating the library (`pip install scikit-learn --upgrade`). The current version allows for `penalty='none'`.

Comment: Now I have version `0.24.2` and I get almost the same result: `array([0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774,
       0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774,
       0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774,
       0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76200774, 0.76570369,
       0.81017708, 0.80962052])`

Comment: Is this the output you got with `penalty='none'`?

Comment: Yes this is the output of exactly your provided code.

Comment: Hmmm... Let me think about it some more then. I'll update the answer once I come up with something.